# Find the value that corresponds to an index

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, find

I have an array 2549x13 double (*M*).

Example lines:

```
-7.8095 -4.4135 -0.0881  2.5159  6.3142  6.9519  4.9788  2.9109  0.6623 -0.9269  0.3172  1.2445 -0.0730
 4.5819  6.2371  5.8721  6.1824  5.2074  4.8656  5.0269  5.3340  3.6919  1.3608 -0.5443  0.2871 -1.2070
-6.2273 -3.7767  1.1829  2.8522  3.2428  0.5261 -3.5535 -7.7743 -8.4391 -9.8188 -6.0503 -5.8805 -7.7700
-2.2157 -3.2100 -4.4400 -3.5898 -0.8901  3.4061  6.5631  7.2028  4.3082 -0.7742 -5.0963 -3.1837  0.4372
 5.5682  5.5393  3.4691  0.6789  1.7320  4.4472  3.7622  1.0194 -0.5362 -3.1721 -6.1281 -6.3959 -6.1932
 0.9707 -0.2701 -3.8883 -8.8974 -7.0375 -1.5085  5.4171  6.0831  2.9852 -2.3474 -4.5637 -3.7378  1.3236
-2.811   0.0164  2.7208  5.7862  7.3344  8.3504  9.0635  8.4271  2.7669 -2.1403 -2.2003 -0.9940  0.7729
 4.2382  3.3532  3.5475  7.9209 11.7933 14.3181 13.6289 12.9553 13.7464 14.1331 14.3814 16.7949 15.9003
-0.0539 -2.7059 -3.8141 -2.7531 -1.7465  0.9190  2.2220  0.7268  1.5436  1.0426  2.3535  3.0269  6.4798
```

I also have the indices of some values I need, 2549x5 double(*inde*).

Example lines:

```
 4  5   6   7   8
 0  1   2   3   4
 3  4   5   6   7
 6  7   8   9   10
-1  0   1   2   3
 6  7   8   9   10
 5  6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14
11  12  13  14  15
```

I want now to create a new array/matrix with the actual values. So, to find in the array *M* the values corresponding to the indices *inde*.

However, if the index (in *inde*) is equal to zero, I would like to take the values corresponding to the indeces 1,2,3,4 of that row.
If the index is -1 or 15, I would like to insert an NaN in the new array/matrix.
If the index is 14, I would like to take the values corresponding to 10,11,12,13.
So I would like to obtain:

```
 2.5159  6.3142  6.9519    4.9788    2.9109
 NaN     4.5819  6.2371  5.8721    6.1824
 1.1829  2.8522  3.2428    0.5261   -3.5535
 3.4061  6.5631  7.2028    4.3082   -0.7742
 NaN
-1.5085  5.4171  6.0831    2.9852   -2.3474
 7.3344  8.3504  9.0635    8.4271    2.7669
 14.1331  14.3814  16.7949   15.9003 NaN
 NaN
```

Very grateful to anyone who could help with this.

Comment: There are many problems in your question. First of all MATLAB doesn't identify indexes to be zero. So one of your conditions is invalid. I assume that you mean the first index. After that, your desired matrix has some problems. 2nd row has no element in the last column. Same is the problem with 8th row. i.e. there is no element in its first column. & what is NA? is it a 1x5 row vector?

I am able to produce your desired result considering `NA` to be a row of  all `NaN` and randomly filling the missing elements in the 2nd & 8th row! I'll post the answer when you clarify the mentioned problems

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Re indexes: What I did is to identify the maximum value in the matrix *M* for each row. `[Peak Ind] = max(M, [], 2);` Then I needed to consider 2 values before and after the maximum value. `inde = bsxfun(@plus,Ind, -2:2);` This is why I obtain zeros in the indexes.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Re desired matrix: What I would like to have is 2 values before and after the maximum value. However, when there is an index of 0 in *inde* it means that my max value was in the 2nd colum of matrix *M*. Therefore, I need to consider only 1 value preceding the max value, and 2 values following the max value. This is why the last value of the 2nd row is missing. Same for the 8th row. Here the max value is in the 2nd last column. Therefore, I need to consider 2 values preceding the max value, and 1 value following the max value. That's why the first value of the 8th row is missing.

Comment: However, I could have NA instead of the missing values.

Comment: What is `NA`? ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: I have zeros as indexes because of the code I used here: `inde = bsxfun(@plus,Ind, -2:2);` It takes the indexes *Ind* of the maximum value, which do start from 1 and not zero, and then it subtract -2 and +2. So for example, if the maximum value was in the position 2, then the indexes of the 2 values preceding the maximum are 0 and 1; and the indexes of the 2 values following the maximum value are 3 and 4.Of course, because the maximum value was at the position 2, it means that the matrix *M* does not contain any value associated to index 0.

Comment: Apologies, with NA I mean NaN values.

Comment: What you just mentioned, in some above comments of yours , is a completely different condition that is mentioned nowhere in the post! where did you state in the question that you are arranging on the basis of peak elements?  You just wrote that you need the values corresponding to the values in `inde`!  That makes no difference except for row 2 and 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the desired array:

```
rows = size(M, 1);                   % number of rows in M and inde
cols = size(inde, 2);                % number of columns in inde
N = [nan(rows, 2) M nan(rows, 2)];   % pad M with 2 columns of NaN values 
                                     %   on left and right
inde = inde + 2;                     % change indices to account for padding
P = zeros(rows, cols);               % preallocate result matrix
nanrow = nan(1, cols);               % make a row of all NaN values


for row_num = 1:rows
   P(row_num,:) = N(row_num, inde(row_num,:));   % get values from N
   if sum(isnan(P(row_num,:))) > 1   % if 2 NaN values, original index was -1 or 15
      P(row_num,:) = nanrow;         %   so make it all NaN's
   end
end
```

(I dislike leaving that stray `2` in there when padding, but I was unsure what the expected result was for different numbers of columns of `inde`, if that's even a concern. Perhaps `floor(cols/2)`?)

Since MATLAB won't allow you to have matrices with rows of unequal length, for rows in which there are indices of `-1` or `15`, I've inserted a row of all `NaN` values. This can obviously be changed to whatever you prefer by modifying the line inside the `if` clause.

Results using `M` and `inde` from your example:

```
P =    
    2.51590    6.31420    6.95190    4.97880    2.91090
        NaN    4.58190    6.23710    5.87210    6.18240
    1.18290    2.85220    3.24280    0.52610   -3.55350
    3.40610    6.56310    7.20280    4.30820   -0.77420
        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
   -1.50850    5.41710    6.08310    2.98520   -2.34740
    7.33440    8.35040    9.06350    8.42710    2.76690
   14.13310   14.38140   16.79490   15.90030        NaN
        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I suggest not to mix numbers and characters in your matrix since it would become a cell-structure which is harder to handle.
So I assume for the rest of my answer that you want to put zeros (or any error value, -999 for instance is sometimes used) where you want to modify your data. Assuming **A** is your data matrix and **i** your indexes' matrix :

```
B=zeros(size(i));
for j=1:size(i,1)
    if (prod(i(j,:))==0)
        k=find(i(j,:)==0);
        B(j,k+1:end)= A(j,i(j,k+1:end));
        m=find(i(j,:)<0);
        if (~isempty(m)) 
            B(j,:)= 0;
        end
    else
    B(j,:)= A(j,i(j,:));
    end
end
```

I get :

```
 2.5159    6.3142    6.9519    4.9788    2.9109
      0    4.5819    6.2372    5.8722    6.1824
 1.1830    2.8522    3.2429    0.5261   -3.5535
 3.4061    6.5632    7.2028    4.3083   -0.7742
     0         0         0         0         0
-1.5086    5.4171    6.0831    2.9853   -2.3475
 7.3344    8.3505    9.0635    8.4271    2.7670
```

Comment: When I try to run this code, an error appears: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Comment: The loop stops working when j is equal to 64. From 64 onwards the matrix B is full of zeros, and the error I reported above appears.

Comment: I updated my question, as there are other two exceptions to zero and -1 (when the index is equal to 14 or 15).